# How to avoid the OpenCV out of memory exception?

Tags: c#, opencv

I am using OpenCvSharp and this code to get the position of a user's eyes.

```
CvCapture cap = CvCapture.FromCamera(CaptureDevice.Any);
using (CvWindow w = new CvWindow("Eye Tracker"))
{

    while (CvWindow.WaitKey(10) < 0 && beginn) //beginn)
    {
        using (IplImage img = cap.QueryFrame())
        using (IplImage smallImg = new IplImage(new CvSize(Cv.Round(img.Width / Scale), Cv.Round(img.Height / Scale)), BitDepth.U8, 1))
        {

            using (IplImage gray = new IplImage(img.Size, BitDepth.U8, 1))
            {
                Cv.CvtColor(img, gray, ColorConversion.BgrToGray);
                Cv.Resize(gray, smallImg, Interpolation.Linear);
                Cv.EqualizeHist(smallImg, smallImg);
            }

            using (CvHaarClassifierCascade cascade = CvHaarClassifierCascade.FromFile(@"D:\haarcascade_eye.xml"))
            using (CvMemStorage storage = new CvMemStorage())
            {
                storage.Clear();
                CvSeq<CvAvgComp> eyes = Cv.HaarDetectObjects(smallImg, cascade, storage, ScaleFactor, MinNeighbors, 0, new CvSize(30, 30));
                if (eyes.Total == 2)
                {

                    // do something
                }
                w.Image = img;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

It works, but the program gets bigger and bigger in memory till it finally says that it doesn't have enough and points at

```
CvSeq<CvAvgComp> eyes = Cv.HaarDetectObjects(smallImg, cascade, storage, ScaleFactor, MinNeighbors, 0, new CvSize(30, 30));
```

How to solve this out of memory exception?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and was searching for a solution when I came across your post. After a bit more digging on my own I figured out that calling

```
GC.Collect()
```

at the end of my loop would free up the memory being consumed by the OpenCVSharp camera capture. Even if you have already solved your issue, perhaps this will help some other poor soul who stumbles here from a Google search.